# Boolean Modifier Render Anomaly

Tags: rendering, modifiers

A bit stumped on a boolean modifier situation. I'm using Cycles and a Boolean Mod to remove a Text-to-Mesh "G" and "N" shaped section out of a solid "B" that I created from a Cube and the Spin extruder.

In the Viewport Shading render preview window, everything looks perfect. But when I actually do a test render, the Boolean areas look distorted. Does anyone happen to know why? Or what I can do to fix it? I've used Boolean Modifiers before without any issues. I'll continue researching solutions and try to figure it out, but if anyone can help it'd be appreciated.

[image: Blender Render Preview]

[image: Actual Render]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of your different levels of subdivisions here:

[image]

Just set the Levels render same as Level viewport.

*** UPDATE ***

So i added the text "N", converted it to mesh and added another boolean modifier to your B. Unfortunately i didn't know your font, so i took the default one.

That result didn't look good.

So i added a remesh modifier to the "N" with these settings:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: It is the solution.

Comment: @Chris I don't think common_goldfish can do that ;)

Comment: LOL - you are right

Comment: But anyway, I'm sure this is the solution - and as I said in the comment on common_goldfish's answer, I think it is important to make beginners aware of these things.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This improved the render by leaps and bounds. Worked with booleans before. Never had this happen, so this was new to me.

It's still a tiny little bit rough though. Any tips on how to completely smooth it out? I know a little about the Dyntopo and whatnot. No idea if something like that could clear up the last bits of roughage. (Can't seem to upload an image of the improved render)

Learning a lot here. Thanks for the info.

Comment: you could increase the subsurf modifier steps even more...if my answer helped you, please click the checkmark left of my answer. If you want me to help you with that problem, just provide your blend file....i will check it out

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble adding any files. When I try to drag and drop, it opens up a new browser tab instead. Can't find any way to include the file.

Comment: You cannot drag and drop blend file. Open this https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: I was able to drag and drop PNG's in the OP. It won't let me drag and drop anything in a follow up comment, including PNG's.

Attempting to upload the file using the blend exchange link. It's a 1MB file. It's been sitting there for about half an hour with no movement on the upload bar. Whenever it decides to cooperate, I'll get the file posted.

Comment: For the love of, some of the stuff on this forum is completely bass-ackwards. Anyway, here's the link for the file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7z87KOKM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7z87KOKM/)

Comment: thank you for your blend file. i updated my answer. My solution proposal is to use a remesh modifier for your "N"

Comment: Thanks man. That looks fantastic. Didn't even think of using a remesh.

Edit: quick clarification - That looks like a screen cap from inside Blender? Is that how it looks after it's been rendered? It's the actual render image that was wonky.

Comment: rendered it looks like this: [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh9jA.png don't know what settings you have but it took eternal to render....and it wasn't ready...but i think it looked already good

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a "B", converting it into mesh, and then in edit mode  selecting it and doing a **limited dissolve**.

Extrude the face of the "B", and it will have less geometry to get in the way of your boolean.

I am showing you wire frame view below.  [image: B]

Comment: I appreciate the tip. My big question is why it looks perfect in Blender, then distorts in the actual rendering. I'm not understanding the discrepancy.

Comment: Although this shows a possible aternative way of constructing the B, it's no solution for the problem and won't help others that struggle with the discrepancy in viewport and render resolution. I think this is more important than showing alternatives, because I often see tutorials where they mostly work in the viewport and only a few tutors mention that you should care for the resolution settings for rendering if you don't want unpleasant surprises.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: i totally agree with you. But even worse - what i really hate is, if the tutorial shows a great tornado with cars and cows flying through the air in the beginning and if you watch the tutorial until the end the tutorial maker doesn't even explain 5% of that tornado, but just shitty basic vortex wind....so for all you tutorial watchers (as i am) out there: always first scroll to the end of the tutorial and check, what the real result is like....